# Loading user edits from local storage from multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load multiple saved elements as part of the local storage for the website planner I am making as part of when the website checks for existing saved elements when it initially loads.

I cannot get this to work properly unfortunately, seemingly I can't load multiple elements all at once.

Only one of them would be able to load, if I try loading two or more at a time it won't have the desired effect.

```
<script>
    function checkEdits() {
        if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
            document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
    }   
</script>
```

This code works fine as I am only loading "edit1", but I also want to load "edit2" and "edit3" and so on.
If I add `"document.getElementById("edit2").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;"` under the code to get "edit1" what is meant to appear on the planner for "edit2" is just the same as what is supposed to appear for "edit1" for some reason.

Can this be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: How are you saving data to the localstorage ?

Comment: <script>
    function saveEdits1() { 
    var editElem = document.getElementById("edit1");
    var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
    localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;
    }
    </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, I think your `userEdits` in localstorage is getting overwritten

```
 function saveEdits1() 
 { 
     var editElem = document.getElementById("edit1"); 
     var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML; 
     localStorage.userEdits1 = userVersion; 
 }

 function saveEdits2() 
 { 
     var editElem = document.getElementById("edit2"); 
     var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML; 
     localStorage.userEdits2 = userVersion; 
 }


function checkEdits() 
{
    if(localStorage.userEdits1!=null)
        document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits1;
    if(localStorage.userEdits2!=null)
        document.getElementById("edit2").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits2;
}
```

**Edit**

You can even use a single array for all edit data:

```
 function saveEdits() 
 { 
     var editsToStore = [];
     var editElem, userVersion;
     for(i=0; i<NO_OF_FIELDS; i++) 
     {
         editElem = document.getElementById("edit"+(i+1)); 
         userVersion = editElem.innerHTML; 
         editsToStore.push(userVersion);
     }
     localStorage.setItem('edits', editsToStore);
 }

 function CheckEdits()
 {
     var editsOb = localstorage.edits;
     for(i=0; i<NO_OF_FIELDS; i++) 
     {
         document.getElementById("edit"+(i+1)).innerHTML = editsOb[i];              
     }
 }
```

Comment: I believe that it was the issue, but there seems to be another issue where the content as part of the "edit1" element appears 100% correctly but the element "edit2" content appears just as "undefined". (this was with the original code provided, haven't tried your newer code yet)

Comment: @Sebastian after the array approach ?

Comment: Array approach doesn't seem to load anything. I can't use the array approach regardless because I have buttons on my planner to save each day on the planner separately (e.g. Monday button has "saveEdits1()", Tuesday has "saveEdits2()"), so I don't want everything saved at once (just one element at a time).

Comment: Got it working now - works perfectly. Had element incorrectly named somewhere. Thanks :)